# How to interpret a Google "Someone is trying to sign in to your account from another device" message?

Tags: authentication, account-security, multi-factor, google

I received this message on my Pixel 4a phone yesterday evening:

[image]

I pressed "No, it's not me" and then saw this message:

[image]

I was at home with a cat and five-year-old son. I was cooking and my son was playing with the cat. My phone was next to me but none of us were using any devices that interact with Google. The messages on the phone gave no details about the device and software trying to log in.

The first message shows the Bluetooth logo. If Bluetooth was involved then does that mean that the login attempt was happening in my home? Was it the cat? I really don't understand.

The messages were unhelpful, and scary and I have no idea what to do. I changed the password of my Google account but the account security section of my Google account website doesn't mention the attempted login event. Was it real?

How can I understand what happened?

Comment: Did you change your password by clicking the button "Change password"? To be safe I'd rather open directly the google account page "indipendently"... **If** this was something shady, the button would be fake, bringing you to a fake website where they could have collected your password... Be very carefuly when opening links from messages if you aren't 1000% sure of the sender

Answer (score 0):

Here are ways to see your login history and login events:

1. https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/device-activity
2. https://myaccount.google.com/notifications?pli%3D1&origin=5
3. Open the link saying "Last account activity: X minutes ago, **Details**" at the bottom of https://mail.google.com/mail

This must be enough to see IP addresses and geographical locations. If there's something you don't recognize, change your password and make sure your devices are malware free.

If I were you, I'd provide google with a backup email address and give them your phone number - both could aid in restoring access later on if someone steals it.